# Unable to call new Date inside data property in component in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm following the [Vue.js tutorial](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Getting-Started) and attempting to add a dynamically bound title. [The example works as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/isachenx/5612scq3/).

However, when attempting to call new Date().toLocalString() from a component, where the `data` property must be a function returning the object and not an object itself, Vue complains with `(intermediate value).toLocalString is not a function`. [Check it out on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mjom5v9r6y)

How can I use new Date inside a Vue component?

Comment: You should always read the message the exception is printing and test your code bit by bit. If you try to run your code in browser console you'll find that `toLocalString()` gives an Exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the method `toLocalString()` which does not exists, maybe you are trying to use `toLocaleString()` instead?